# EventListener for checkboxes not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lot of checkboxes are created through this loop, and I want that when one is clicked, the words "Not Showing, " turn to "Showing." I'm using object.on(), here object is my class for my table, but when I click on a checkbox, not only does the checkbox not check, but it continually fires this function and no words change, instead it just console.logs "Clicked" hundreds of times. Then the program breaks. Anybody know why? Thank you.

```
    data.forEach((row) => {
      myTable += "<tr>" + "<td>" + `<label id="label" ><input type="checkbox"><span> Not showing</span></label>` + "</td>"+ "<td>" + row.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + app.nations[row.nation] + "</td></tr>"
      $('.table-sticky-container').on('click', 'label', function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
        var checked = $('input').is(':checked');
        $('span').text(checked ? ' Showing' : ' Not showing');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Please turn this into a reproducible minimal example in form of an embedded runnable snippet, thank you.

Comment: Every time you iterate through the list you're creating an additional handler.  All of them are firing every time you click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating a new listener on ALL `.table-sticky-container` every time you iterate your loop. On top of which you're telling jQuery to check all `input` elements to see if they're checked.

What you should do is put your event delegate outside the loop and use relative paths for your logic, like this

```
// set the delegate
$('.table-sticky-container').on('click','label', function() {
    let txt = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked') ? "Showing" : "Not showing";
    $(this).find('span').html(txt);
})
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!